# PHP Goutte / CURL - Complete ASPX Form

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-scraping, goutte

I'm trying to get data from here: https://wyobiz.wy.gov/Business/FilingSearch.aspx

I'm trying to check if business name is free or not.
But this website is **asp.net web forms**, and whole website is one big form. 
And I don't know how to get data from this form.

I think problem is with:

```
        '__VIEWSTATE' => '',
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => '9E6EC73D',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => '',
```

Is it possible send request and get returned data in PHP? 
Because, this code is returning

> The current node list is empty.

Thank you.

My code:

```
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://wyobiz.wy.gov/Business/FilingSearch.aspx');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Search')->form();
    $formValues = $form->getValues();
    $crawler = $client->submit($form, array(
        '__VIEWSTATE' => $formValues['__VIEWSTATE'],
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $formValues['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'],
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $formValues['__EVENTVALIDATION'],
        'ctl00$MainContent$myScriptManager' => 'MainContent_myScriptManager',
        'ctl00$MainContent$txtFilingName' => 'Google',
        'ctl00$MainContent$searchOpt' => 'chkSearchStartWith',
        'ctl00$MainContent$txtFilingID' => null,
    ));
    $crawler->filter('body')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text() . "\n";
    });
```

---

Conclusion: Goutte **SUCKS** Goutte's support **SUCKS**!

Comment: I'm starting to think, that it's not possible...

Comment: `$formValues['__VIEWSTATE']` what's the output of this variable ? does it empty or not ?

Comment: @hassan no it's not empty. It's returning really long string.

Comment: I can't get why it's not working. __VIEWSTATE , __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION is set correctly....

Comment: i think the issue in the parameters you are sending; you are not sending the full required parameters

Comment: BTW I think problem is with __ASYNCPOST. In Goutte I can't set it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm not familiar with goutte, but using this package [w3zone/crawler](https://github.com/w3zone/crawler) I've made a quick example to scrap the content of that link:

install it using:

```
composer require w3zone/Crawler
```

then use it for your case as follows:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use w3zone\Crawler\{Crawler, Services\phpCurl};

$crawler = new Crawler(new phpCurl);

$link = 'https://wyobiz.wy.gov/Business/FilingSearch.aspx';

$homePage = $crawler->get($link)->run();

preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)"\s*/>#', $homePage['body'], $viewState);
preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="(.*?)"\s*/>#', $homePage['body'], $viewGen);
preg_match('#<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)"\s*/>#', $homePage['body' ], $eventVal);

$postData = array(
    '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewState[1],
    '__LASTFOCUS' => '',
    '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $viewGen[1],
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventVal[1],
    'ctl00$MainContent$myScriptManager' => 'MainContent_myScriptManager',
    'ctl00$MainContent$txtFilingName' => 'test',
    'ctl00$MainContent$searchOpt' => 'chkSearchStartWith',
    'ctl00$MainContent$txtFilingID' => '',
    'ctl00$MainContent$cmdSearch' => 'Search',
    '__ASYNCPOST' => 'true',
    'ctl00$MainContent$myScriptManager' => 'ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$MainContent$cmdSearch',
);

$response = $crawler->post(['url' => $link, 'data' => $postData])->dumpHeaders()->run();

echo "<textarea style='width: 90%; height: 200px;'>".$response['body']."</textarea>";
```

Comment: Thanks,
Have you tried this?  
What happens if you remove __LASTFOCUS, __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT?

Comment: no, you may try, but as they holds empty values it will be okey if you included them;

Comment: did this fixed your issue ?

Comment: Hey, no, I have been told, that this website have some protection from robotic search or something. 
I'm trying to get more info.

Comment: BTW. Could you please try this? May be it's stn wrong with my project.

Comment: after removing those three inputs `__LASTFOCUS, __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT` still working fine

Comment: Oh, deleted script and created new, now your code is working. But how can I get just status?  `<span class="resFile2"><span class="resultField">Status: </span>Inactive - Administratively Dissolved (Tax) </span>`

Comment: you may need to use `HTMLDOM` as the goute using , or using regex , split and match your required data;

Comment: if you have issues or suggestion with the [crawler](https://github.com/w3zone/crawler) package you may pull request there or open new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the ASP asynchronous response isn't HTML - it's text with HTML in it:

```
<html>
1|#||4|6079|updatePanel|ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ucLicenseLookup_UpdtPanelGridLookup|
                <div class="modal-window-lookup-results fade bs-example-modal-lg in">
                    <div class="modal-header">
    [...]

</html>
```

So, when goutte feeds it to browser-kit, it breaks. Goutte doesn't suck -
 you just can't feed it non-HTML garbage.

To get around this in a hurry I just did:

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', $url, $params);
// this is a broken crawler because response is not html!

$html = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
$html = substr($html, strpos($html, "<div"));
$html = substr($html, 0, strpos($html, "|hiddenField|")-3);
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html>$html</html>";
$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler($html);
print $crawler->html();
```

Comment: Please learn how to use the markdown language to properly format your input. That **preview** window exists for a reason - I am pretty sure that you didn't mean to format your code like this?!